# symfony 1.4.8 conflict with PHP 5.4.7 and Apache 2.4.3

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, xampp, symfony-1.4

I recently updated my Xampp server (from 1.7 >> 1.8) and since then I'm no longer able to run my projects written in Symfony 1.4.8.

It says:

> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

But it has permissions!

Actually it works fine with older version of Xampp. Is it possible that Symfony 1.4.8 is not compatible with Apache 2.4 or PHP 5.4? I'm using Windows 8 Enterprise, but also tested on Windows 7 Ultimate and same problem exists.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my config:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:1111
Listen 127.0.0.1:1111
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:1111>
  DocumentRoot "D:\AMir\PROJECTS\BarzinMehr\web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "D:\AMir\PROJECTS\BarzinMehr\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  Alias /sf C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\data\web\sf
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\data\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What or where are you getting that error from? If there is a compatibility issue, its unlikely you would get an error like that and instead see a php error.

Comment: Are you sure that you've properly configured the whole stack as you had with previous one? Sounds like Apache does not have privileges to read your dir. Trivia: copy your project to another location and assign chmod 777 to whole directory. Does it solve a problem?

Comment: @datasage: i get this error when i run my project.

Comment: A quick google search show that the error is an Apache 403 error. Something in broken in the Apache config, or Apache does not actually have permission to the directory, that its being told to use, probably more of a serverfault type question.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk: yeah! it's exactly like before! nothings changed! i cant show you the config if you want! i'm sure that my directory has all the permissions. it's killing me! cuz nothing's changed everything is the same just i upgraded my xampp server!

Comment: This depends on how this particular vhost is set up. Are you using the default `DocumentRoot`, or a `VirtualHost` clause for this?

Comment: (I am quite certain that symfony 1.4.x is compatible both with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4 - that is not the problem here).

Comment: @datasage: yeah! but what is broken?! i'm using the exact same thing that i've used before, nothing more! so why appache can't figure it out. btw, apache starts without any problems.

Comment: Try adding an `Order allow,deny` to your `Directory` container, that might be worth a go.

Comment: @halfer: nope! didn't work!

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` is the default one? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: yeah it's the default one! i didn't change it!

Comment: Couple of other things to try. First, try stopping Xampp/Apache, and then ensure you don't get the same error (the website should of course not respond in your browser at all). If it still responds with the error then your old Apache installation may still be lurking and running. Next, ensure you reboot your machine - did you do so after the Xampp upgrade? Lastly adding the right owner to various levels of folders in "D:\AMir\PROJECTS\BarzinMehr\web" may be necessary - what user does Apache/Xampp run under?

Comment: Also, please edit into your question what version of Windows you are using. This should always be stated on questions like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after struggling with this problem for so many days, i finally found the solution and i'm taking it here in favour of anyone else who might face this problem. according to [this article](http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/06/fun-with-wamp-server-and-apache-2-4-2/) (thanks to the writer!) all i had to do was this:

change each Directory block like this:

```
<Directory "your address">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "your address">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

it seems that **Allow** was dropped in favor of new directive **Require** in **apache 2.4**(according to [documentation for version apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html))

Comment: +1 for taking the time to report back with the solution. That first sentence sums up exactly what this site is for.

Comment: @SDC thanks, of course! I have saved so many days of searching by just looking at the answers of others in this place so many times, so i'm gonna do the same for others!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the .htaccess file and accessing the `index.php` file directly. If this works (or at least produces a PHP error, rather than an apache error), it probably means that mod_rewrite is not enabled, and the `.htaccess` is not working as expected.

I would recommend removing the:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

and it's closing tag from the .htaccess file if they are present because if the module isn't installed, it's better to get an error that it isn't installed, rather than the site just not work in a strange way.

If the above doesn't solve the issue, take a look at apache's error log - this often contains clues.

Comment: @rjmunro : nope! nothing changed!

Comment: @rjmunro: i checked apache error log too! it just keeps saying: `client denied by server configuration: D:/AMir/PROJECTS/BarzinMehr/web/`  
or  
`client denied by server configuration: D:/AMir/PROJECTS/BarzinMehr/web/favicon.ico`

Comment: @Firouziam - that error will give you something to web-search, let us know what you find!